# Assistance extracting parameters from URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery, url-parameters

I am attempting to extract 2 parameters from a URL string using jQuery and just do not have enough experience to figure it out.

Here is a sample of a URL:

```
http://awebsite.com/index.html?ref=toys&zip=30003
```

I would like to grab and assign these 2 parameters as variables. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?');
var ref = params[1].split('=')[1];
var zip = params[1].split('&')[1];
```

So that var ref would be `toys` and var zip would be `30003`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can find yout answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do it more along the lines of what I have? That seems like a lot of code just to grab 2 parameters(not that it would affect load time, just want to keep it as clean as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the query string on `&` so that you get each parameter in a string, then split each one on `=`.

Example:

```js
var url = 'http://awebsite.com/index.html?ref=toys&zip=30003';

var params = url.substr(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
var ref = params[0].split('=')[1];
var zip = params[1].split('=')[1];

// show result in StackOverflow snippet
document.writeln(ref);
document.writeln(zip);
```